# Differences between 2 statements in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I tried to make selection of an item in the radiobuttonlist with the help of Jquery.
I had tried with the following statement for a long:

```
$('#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_RblSendTo input[type="radio"]')[0].attr("checked",true)
```

But I dint get the selection. After minutes tested with the following :

```
$('#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_RblSendTo input[type="radio"]')[0].checked = true
```

It worked.
Unable to know what's wrong with my first statement ?

Comment: `)[0]` retrieves the DOM element object and `attr()` can't use with that since it's a jQuery method.... to make it work do `....."radio"]').prop("checked",true)`

Comment: Yes, for that element itself I'm attaching attr. Why it's not working ?

Comment: You can't use `attr()` method with dom element object

Comment: you mean 'attr' will not work whereas 'prop' will work here ?

Comment: both would work with jQuery object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first statement you get the DOM element with [0]. That element doesn't have a method named `attr`.

`.attr()` is a jQuery method that can only be used with jQuery objects.
`$("input")` returns a jQuery object whereas `$("input")[0]` gets the first DOM element ("node") matched by the jQuery object.

If you drop the `[0]` in your first statement, it should work.

Comment: So, 'checked' means a direct javascript statement only can get the result whereas the jquery methods cant fetch the DOM objects information. Is my statement right ?

Comment: @SreekanthReddy no.  You can use jquery to get DOM information just fine - but not by using `[0]`.

Comment: If we use array of index it provides dom element only right ?

Comment: Right. it is equivalent to .get() (http://api.jquery.com/get/). But get() has some more functional tricks like negative indexer.

Answer (score 0):

`$("selector")[0]` gets a jquery object(array), takes the first entry and returns the equivalent *DOM* node.

So it's no longer a jquery object, so you can't call jquery methods on it.

To fix, you can remove the `[0]` part:

```
$("...").attr("checked", true);
```

or, if you only want one, use `.first()`:

```
$("...").first().attr("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already comments and answers pointing to the fact that `$(...)[0]` unwraps first DOM element from jQuery return.

What I want to add is that it is not how you should use return of `$` function.

If you want to unwrap DOM node you really should use `$.get`:

```
$('.myclass').get(0) // returns first DOM element from the jquery wrapped node list
```

If you want to get only first item that will match your selector, use pseudo selectors:

```
$('.myclass:first') // returns first DOM element wrapped

$('.myclass:eq(n)') // returns Nth DOM element wrapped
```

Another thing to mention is if you decided to plug in jquery today be consistant in the way you are using it.

What I mean by that is if you are using jquery to select elements chain it to attach event handlers and access/change properties of the DOM elements. Do not mix and match!  When you are just using jQuery for DOM manipulations you are using very small API that is battle-tested and cross-platform, and a lot of side-cases are taken care of for you.

If you want to go for browser native capabilities do it, remove jquery completely ( check http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ for reference) but be advised that you are on your own if you happen to find yourself in need to support desktop browsers older than IE9 and/or older WinMo/iOS/android devices. It is all nice and sound when you know your clients use evergreen browsers, but jquery have more than a thousand different browser quirks being taken care of.